# activating turn off switch when measured value is greater than constant (LabVIEW)

Tags: comparison, labview

I am measuring a varying voltage value and when it exceeds some threshold, currently set at .25, as shown in the image, I want the power supply to be cut off.

[image: diagram screenshot]

I thought I could just use a 'greater than' comparison to activate the power off button but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Assuming you've tested the "OUTP OFF" command functionality outside of this environment and it works: are any of the other boolean controls on? Your boolean array will only ever output 2 if the "Off" control is the only one that is true.

Comment: @Dave_St Assuming these Boolean controls are buttons with `Latch when Released` mechanical action, and the loop time is short, then I guess it's unlikely that more than one of them will be True at once. A better solution would be to use [`Search 1D Array`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/search_1d_array/) instead of the Boolean array to number function though.

Answer (score 0):

Any wire on a LabVIEW diagram can only have one source. It can be wired to any number of inputs but only one output - otherwise, what should the value on the wire be, if the two outputs returned different values?

If you want to use the result of your comparison to activate the 'off' case, instead of the `Off` control, you'll have to either:

- Disconnect the `Off` control and connect this wire to the output of the `Greater Than` comparison function instead, or
- Insert an `Or` function in the wire and connect the output of the comparison to the unused input of the Or. That way the 'off' case will be activated if either the comparison is True, or the button is clicked.